# Python basic for loop clarification

Tags: python, for-loop

I have 3 years of PHP experience and currently trying to catch up with Python on sololearn.
The first question in Intermediate Python that checks my Python knowledge goes like this:

```
n = [2, 4, 6, 8]
res = 1
for x in n[1:3]:
  res *= x
```

I am confused why the result is 24, my logic is that `n[1:3]` means `n[1] * n[2] * n[3]` so `4 * 6 * 8`.

I searched on google about for loops in Python but i only find stuff about the `range()` function, couldn't find an explanation for the `:` operator

Comment: Hint: `print([2, 4, 6, 8][1:3])`. Your loop iterates over the list returned from that

Comment: Search about `slicing`, not about `for loop`

Comment: If you want all elements except `2`, use `n[1:]`

Comment: `range` and slicing work the same way: the upper bound is *exclusive*. `list(range(1, 3)) == [1,2,3][1:3] == [1,2]`.

Answer (score 1):

It does n[1] * n[2] = 4 *6 = 24.
Read more about list slicing:
https://railsware.com/blog/python-for-machine-learning-indexing-and-slicing-for-lists-tuples-strings-and-other-sequential-types/